# Red Hat restart not show correct login page?

Tags: linux, rhel

[image]

When I restart my Red Hat, the screen only show the snapshot page without login page.

But I can use SSH to login to start VNC. Then VNC also working well with normal X screen. 
Does any export know how to fix this ?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How about logging to single user [\[ mode \]](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html) and do an init 5 from there.

Comment: Is this the first time? Is it freshly installed or it were starting properly in Graphical mode earlier ? Seems like the issue is with the graphical mode or graphic driver.

Comment: @ankidaemon It were starting properly in Graphical mode earlier. We just deployed one apache and vnc on it. Then the system is like this.

Comment: @sjsam, How to login one single user? This screen show up after OS booting up. I have no place to input command. But I can use SSH to connect it to input some commands. Any ideas?

Comment: @noel: login using ssh and execute command #  init 1

Comment: @noellee : The link I've given you explains that. You need to get to the Single User Mode using GRUB>

Comment: @ankidaemon , yes i tried login as Single User Mode, but not cannot fix this issue. Reboot the OS is still hand in my Snapshot screen.

Comment: @noel: In that case, trying checking boot logs in /var/log/boot.log or using dmesg for any type error or failure..

Comment: Starting certmonger: /usr/sbin/certmonger: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]  That's one of my failed in boot log. Does that the root cause?

Comment: hmm. certmonger hanging was one of the bug in redhat. I am not sure if this is rectified. Follow this link https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=891950 and read comment of "NevilleDNZ". Might help. This is probably caused by vnc installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ankidaemon's help.
Finally I found the issue was caused by upgrade of OpenSSL which miss 2 import libraries, one is libssl.so.10, another one is libcrypto.so.10.

Then I checked my /usr/lib64 and find different version of my above mentioned libraries.

The solution is soft link them by:

```
# ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10

# ln -s /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```